# Autofac injection to custom Web-Api FilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a custom ExceptionFilter that logs all uncaught exceptions inside Web-Api controllers. I would like to use Autofac, to inject ILog configurations to it.

My question is how to do so ? Autofac site has almost no explanation on how to do so.

CustomFilter:

```
public class ApiControllerErrorFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("ApiLog");
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        log.Error("Error: ", actionExecutedContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

p.s.
For clarification, I also have a custom Filter for normal controllers and I was able to successfully configure it.

Filter for normal controllers:

```
public class ControllerErrorFilterAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public ICustomLogSettings Log { get; set; }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Log.GetLogger.Error("Error: ", filterContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

Log Configuration:

```
    builder.Register(c => new BaseLog()).As<ICustomLogSettings>().InstancePerRequest();
    builder.RegisterFilterProvider();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of [these examples](http://alexmg.com/fluent-interface-for-filter-overrides-in-the-autofac-mvc-and-web-api-integrations/) may help, especially:

```cs
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

builder.Register(c => new MyWebApiFilter())
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ValuesController>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

From that, it shows me that you can register a filter that gets resolved just like any other service, this means you should be able to do:

```cs
public class ApiControllerErrorFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILog _log

    public ApiControllerErrorFilterAttribute(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        _log.Error("Error: ", actionExecutedContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

And then be able to register it like so:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<ApiControllerErrorFilterAttribute>()
    .AsWebApiActionFilterFor<ValuesController>()
    .InstancePerApiRequest();
```

Then of course, you need to set up registration for resolving ILog, which will be very similar to [this part of the wiki](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Log4-Net-Integration).

Comment: had to add IAutofacExceptionFilter interface to my filter and change AsWebApiActionFilterFor to AsExceptionFilterFor, but other than that worked like a charm. Thanks